# Is it possible to set session id (or JSESSIOINID) value manually in Java?

Tags: java, session

As the title says. In [PHP for example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) I can set the session id manually to handle the session with some logic based on it. I have generated hash code from some workflow and would like to set it as the session id. I know some implied this could be bad practice if not careful but as team member I was directed to look and try to do this task.

So could session ID set manually ?

Note that I mean the actual session ID not just the cookie named JSESSIOINID that being set on first request. I need the session as it is with only session id set manually.

Update: I'm using JBoss but I'd appreciate any generic answer or at the very least for JBoss EAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No standardized way to it. Only custom way through the container's own API

Comment: It seems that way. Only tomcat I know that provides `setId(java.lang.String id)` method in `org.apache.catalina.Session` interface

Answer (score 2):

For Tomcat, you may be able to create a custom session manager (see [this](http://markmail.org/message/im3wkoeskkgjaphv#query:tomcat%20custom%20session%20Manager+page:1+mid:lgl2bdm26avvjx37+state:results)). You would then have access to the Tomcat Session object and could call [`setId(java.lang.String id)`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Session.html).

Comment: So is this possible in other AS ? Like JBoss ? It seems that it's container implementation dependent, am I right ? I wasn't specific since I targeted generic answer so I updated the question but this answer is really appreciated.